# Generate a rand time

Tags: mysql

I want to set random time value at `created` column, eg:

```
UPDATE review  set created=now()-rand(1,30)
```

But `created=now()-rand(1,30)` doesn't work. How to correct it?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is, at least, very wide term...

Comment: what do you want for `rand(1999,2012)`?

Comment: when i change to rand(1,30) it still can't work

Comment: Again: 1) what does that "doesn't work" mean? 2) what result do you want to achieve?

Comment: it shows Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'rand'

Comment: i want to achieve generate a rand time

Comment: Because http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: why are you generating a random time?  Do you want a random identifier?  What purpose does a random time serve?

Comment: None of these comments just say "hey, rand() takes at most one argument". Also, generating a random time in MySQL is useful for a lot of cases, e.g. between a range. The constant initializer is actually quite interesting too, although don't do anything remotely security-related with it (I can see all the noob queries now... ahhh...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use DATE_ADD or DATE_SUB.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE
   review
SET
   created = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL (24*RAND()) HOUR)
```

Check [the reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to learn how to use date and time functions.

Here a more complex example that generates a random date starting 25 years ago.

```
UPDATE 
    review
SET
    created =
      DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD(
         NOW(), 
         INTERVAL (-24*RAND())-1 YEAR),
         INTERVAL 11*RAND() MONTH),
         INTERVAL 30*RAND() DAY),
         INTERVAL 23*RAND() HOUR),
         INTERVAL 59*RAND() MINUTE),
         INTERVAL 60*RAND() SECOND)
```

Comment: if i want to generate the year. this is my way (NOW(),INTERVAL (24*RAND()) YEAR, INTERVAL (24*RAND())  it shows an eror

Comment: Why do you put two INTERVAL? Check the reference

Comment: Then use two neasted DATE_ADD. Like this DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR), INTERVAL 5 MONTH)

Comment: i want to generate the HOUR and MINUTE  i had looked for the reference some time but still don't know how to write it. thank you